# SignalR - WebSocket Error: Network Error 12030, The connection with the server was terminated abnormally

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis, websocket, signalr

Trying to get SignalR working on the webserver(IIS 8, Server 2012, websockets installed, .NET 4.5) but having no joy.

Works great on my local IIS(windows 8 and connects with websockets)

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
```

and

```
<compilation strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5" debug="false">
```

Set in webconfig

Local signalr logging:

```
[11:26:17 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: Client subscribed to hub 'notificationhub'.
[11:26:17 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: Negotiating with '/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22notificationhub%22%7D%5D'.
[11:26:17 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: webSockets transport starting.
[11:26:17 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: Connecting to websocket endpoint 'ws://localhost:22038/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=W5PmClxV6R32xJpuP5It2NUDVvJXOESGJCrgQYb67z59ODUJFr13zQzgBgTYEfmr4XbgMmRGU3ZncQS3yZU2Hmh%2Fc3h%2F17fh9gRlUOUdnaVYcnls%2BQon%2F7R0ckNw8MnLcrG1pg%3D%3D&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22notificationhub%22%7D%5D&tid=3'.
[11:26:17 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: Websocket opened.
[11:26:17 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: webSockets transport connected. Initiating start request.
[11:26:18 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: The start request succeeded. Transitioning to the connected state.
[11:26:18 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: Now monitoring keep alive with a warning timeout of 13333.333333333332, keep alive timeout of 20000 and disconnecting timeout of 30000
hub start, connection id=01b7a623-5531-496c-a5e1-ab0876e2c1a6
```

Server log:

```
[11:24:01 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: Client subscribed to hub 'notificationhub'.
[11:24:01 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: Negotiating with '/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22notificationhub%22%7D%5D'.
[11:24:02 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: webSockets transport starting.
[11:24:02 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: Connecting to websocket endpoint 'ws://foo.co.uk/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=uibfnMomSreytNZY7UiusFWoTjNWO6%2FNIaBzIM%2FVVSBOXk6SNlyULUH%2FaGWoPynoEbx6sKRfShJG0zrd846uqgdgEK6xQIP2K5j3xfwtBlngGG3i6k%2FYoHNk5subReA3TsCxfw%3D%3D&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22notificationhub%22%7D%5D&tid=10'.
[11:24:03 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: Websocket opened.
SCRIPT12030: WebSocket Error: Network Error 12030, The connection with the server was terminated abnormally

[11:24:03 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: Unclean disconnect from websocket: [no reason given].
[11:24:03 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: Closing the Websocket.
[11:24:03 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: webSockets transport failed to connect. Attempting to fall back.
[11:24:03 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: serverSentEvents transport starting.
[11:24:03 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: This browser doesn't support SSE.
[11:24:03 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: serverSentEvents transport failed to connect. Attempting to fall back.
[11:24:03 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: foreverFrame transport starting.
[11:24:03 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: Binding to iframe's load event.
[11:24:03 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: Iframe transport started.
[11:24:03 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: foreverFrame transport connected. Initiating start request.
[11:24:03 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: The start request succeeded. Transitioning to the connected state.
[11:24:03 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: Now monitoring keep alive with a warning timeout of 13333.333333333332, keep alive timeout of 20000 and disconnecting timeout of 30000
hub start, connection id=cd2af7f4-5f85-40bb-a0a6-f8f8060bedae
```

Even though it appears to be connected using foreverFrame it does not fire the appropriate hub responses.

Answer (score 1):

Nondescript errors like this can occur if there are JSON serialization problems on the server. I would expect a proper exception for most normal exceptions.

In my case I made a really stupid mistake and had TWO properties with the same JsonProperty name in my return message (server side). Basically a cut and paste error that took a while to be noticed because 'SuggestedCities' wan't always populated.

```
public class ValidateZipStateResponse
{
    [JsonProperty("correctedCity")]
    public string CorrectedCity { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("correctedState")]
    public string CorrectedState { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("correctedState")]
    public string[] SuggestedCities { get; set; }
}
```

Make sure client side you enable debugging. It won't help with this error, but in general it's quite useful and you'll see a useful log in the browser console.

```
$.connection.hub.logging = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying the website on my home connection I found it connected to websockets fine.

So I am going to assume there is some kind of Proxy server inbetween my "work" pc and the web server. Of which I have no access to. (Assuming Proxy server over Firewall here).

> [10:33:15 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: Client subscribed to
>   hub 'notificationhub'.
>
> [10:33:15 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: Negotiating with
>   '/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22notificationhub%22%7D%5D'.
>   [10:33:16 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: webSockets transport
>   starting. [10:33:16 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: Connecting
>   to websocket endpoint
>   'ws://blah/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=IxxvgxBhvbsruv2uk0pK%2FPB708bJGvoOJD0oR0vVPgBip%2B7uGy68HEMOw1ikq7%2BuiyX7XqN%2FwYK%2BKgkrBlz9HHuI5HSDQEwRHvSr2Ey1pg2B7FaviRLFcNu8mg2dRWHVKbAkdw%3D%3D&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22notificationhub%22%7D%5D&tid=6'.
>   [10:33:16 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: Websocket opened.
>   [10:33:16 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: webSockets transport
>   connected. Initiating start request. [10:33:16 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard
>   Time)] SignalR: The start request succeeded. Transitioning to the
>   connected state. [10:33:16 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: Now
>   monitoring keep alive with a warning timeout of 13333.333333333332,
>   keep alive timeout of 20000 and disconnecting timeout of 30000 hub
>   start, connection id=7f3eba16-9e7b-450e-a740-a69fa91047b6